# Is there a way to specify regular expression for artifactid in Maven?

Tags: maven

I have a use-case where I want to include dependency on all jars for groupid=X. Is there a way I can do something like this in my POM file?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>X</groupId>
  <artifactId>*</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This should include all jar with version 1.0 and groupID = X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Maven doesn't support this.

I can't think of a good use case for this proposal. The whole point of Maven is to manage your classpath, by pulling in the jars containing the classes you need. I understand that your code may depend on multiple modules, but I would submit that if your code really requires lots and lots of modules from the same group id then perhaps the issue is with the publisher. It's very easy to create a "main" or "common" module that would import the others as dependencies.

Comment: My project has dependency on a project that has some ~30 other dependent jars. I manually added them to our internal maven repository. I hate to type all those dependency one by one in my pom file. I figured specifying a regex for artifact-id would solve my problem. May be there is more efficient way to tackle this use-case ?

Comment: @nadirsaghar Each artifact in Maven has a POM. Pick one of these and add all the other modules as dependencies. This one module is then all you need in your project's POM. Maven will pull down that artiafct and everything it depends on.